# How to create a pool from scratch?

Tags: uniswap

I'm aware that most projects use either uniswap or a fork of it. I wasn't able to find any examples that aren't related to uniswap.

If anyone can point out how I can build my own pool.

Here is the link for Uniswapv2 contracts that I'm learning from
https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/tree/master/contracts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're building your own Uniswap clone, you would need to first deploy the factory and then use it to deploy your trading pools (token pairs) by calling:

```
factory.createPair(tokenA, tokenB)
```

If you're not building your own clone and just looking to interact with an already-deployed Uniswap clone, you could simply connect to that deployed factory and call the same method as described above.